# Is there a way to define the concept of manifolds so it looks more like “generalised affine spaces”?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

What I have in mind is along the lines of this:

Let $M$ a topological space, $V$ a normed vector space, and

$$
  \boxminus \colon M\times M \to V,
$$
$$
  \boxplus \colon M\times V \to M.
$$

Then $M$ is called a *manifold<sup>1</sup> with tangent space $V$*, if
$$
  p \boxplus (q \boxminus p) = q,
$$
$$
  p \boxplus \vec{0} = p
$$
and, for sufficiently small<sup>2</sup> vectors $v,w$,
$$
  (p \boxplus v) \boxplus w \approx p \boxplus (v+w).
$$

Can this set of axioms be made equivalent to the standard definition of manifolds (with an atlas of ball-homeomorphic neighbourhoods)?

Note that rather than requiring the manifold to be locally homeomorphic to a ball in a vector space, I require it to be globally isomorphic to some subset of a vector space, in a way that's locally a homeomorphism.

---

It sure seems to work for simple examples. Christian Blatter suggests $S^1$. Well, if we interpret that as $[0,1]$ with the ends glued together, then we can just define $\theta \boxminus \phi$ as $\theta - \phi$ folded back into the interval $[-\tfrac12, \tfrac12[ \subset V \equiv \mathbb{R}$, and $\theta \boxplus \delta$ as $\theta + \delta$ confined to $[0,1[$. The axioms hold; in fact $\boxplus$ is associative.

The same works for tori of arbitrary dimension. For $S^2$ it immediately gets a bit messier, but I'd figure something Euler-angle-ish should do the trick in much the same way as in $S^1$. Where I'm uncertain is with multi-hole handlebodies, or Klein bottles etc. – and even if all those work, with the general case.

---

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>Evidently, this definition implies at least that the manifold will be path-connected. Likely also other things, but which exactly?</sub>

<sup>2</sup>
<sub>A precise formulation of this: let $\varepsilon>0$, $p\in M$, $v,w \in V$. Then there exists $\eta>0$, such that
$$\left\|\bigl((p \boxplus \eta v) \boxplus \eta w\bigr) \boxminus \bigl(p \boxplus (\eta v + \eta w)\bigr) \right\| < \eta\cdot \varepsilon.$$</sub>

Comment: Try to realize a well known manifold, say $S^1$, along these lines!

Comment: Trying to get intuition here, since I'm not sure I understand what $\boxplus$ and $\boxminus$ are "supposed to be": How do you define $\boxplus$ when $M = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$? (What is your picture of a natural $V$ for this manifold?)

Comment: @mollyerin: $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$, so I'd use $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, where one of the axes represents the tangent space of the angle and the other of the radius. I'd define, for instance, $(\phi,r) \boxplus (\delta_\phi, \delta_r) = ((\phi + \delta_\phi)_{[\text{mod}2\pi]}, \phi \cdot e^{\delta_\phi})$.

Comment: Wait, I meant $(\phi,r) \boxplus (\delta_\phi, \delta_r) = \bigl((\phi + \delta_\phi)_{[\text{mod}2\pi]}, r \cdot e^{\delta_r}\bigr)$ of course.

Comment: I don't have anything concrete to say, but my instinct is that this *may* work for parallelizable manifolds, but probably doesn't other wise.  For whatever reason, I feel like your definition of $\boxminus$ is forcing that.  In any case, it feels as though your definitions are too global in character to replace the usual notion of manifold, which is inherently local in character.  Again, I have nothing concrete now, so I don't yet have counter example.  Have you tried working out the $S^2$ case in detail?

Comment: Also, in case it helps anyone's intuition, on a parallelizable Riemannian manifold $M$, one can use $\exp:M\times T_p M\rightarrow M$ as $\boxplus$.  I'm still not sure what to make of $\boxminus$.